# angular 2 equivalent of react renderToString

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

I am looking for the angular 2 equivalent of `react-dom/server.renderToString`

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';    
// Render the component to a string
const html = renderToString(
  <App />
);
```

What is the simplest code example to transform a directive/component into HTML using NodeJs?

I guess it should be possible with one of these packages:

- @angular/compiler - v2.0.0-rc.2
- @angular/platform-server -
  v2.0.0-rc.2

Comment: What is your goal? You could use ComponentResolver to create ComponentFactory and create component dynamically, then get ComponentRef and then convert HTMLElement to string.

Comment: @kemsky could you provide an answer with code demonstrating that solution?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Components use HTML templates as part of the development process, but we actually compile those templates to Javascript, rather than HTML in order to render them to the browser.

The closest thing that might help you would be to look at https://github.com/angular/universal. This project represents the best way to run your Angular components on the server in a way that renders javascript and HTML and delivers it to the browser via the network.

We can't supply a simple method to "render" to HTML, because any sort of "rendering" involves the entire Angular framework (core, common, template compilation) and processing your entire component tree.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I had a deeper look at angular/universal and they have a function called `renderDocument` which does actually what I need however it is deprecated.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/universal/src/node/render.ts#L110-L120

Comment: Should be something like:
`function (componentType, nodeProviders) {
  return bootstrap(componentType, nodeProviders)
    .then((appRef) => stringifyElement(appRef.location.nativeElement))
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'angular2-universal/polyfills';
import {
  provide,
  REQUEST_URL,
  ORIGIN_URL,
  NODE_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  Bootloader
} from 'angular2-universal';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

const bootloader = new Bootloader({
  platformProviders: [
    {provide: ORIGIN_URL, useValue: 'http://localhost:3000'},
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
  ],
  async: true,
  preboot: false // { appRoot: 'app-root' } // your top level app component selector
});

export function ngApp(req, res) {
  let url = req.originalUrl || '/';

  const config = {
    template: `<!doctype html><html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`,
    directives: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
      {provide: REQUEST_URL, useValue: url},
      ...NODE_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
      ...NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ]
  };

  bootloader.serializeApplication(config)
  .then(html => res.send(html));
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you mix it with express.. guess that's not necessary at all.. why didn't you include the import statements?